# jQuery Masonry / Isotope and fluid images: Momentary overlap on window resize

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I've noticed that when using jQuery Isotope or Masonry with a fluid / responsive website, the elements overlap momentarily whilst the browser window is being resized. Please see the images below, which are screenshots from [this](http://osvaldas.info/examples/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout/) demo. You can also see this happening on the Isotope [website](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html).

Is there anything that can be done to avoid this overlapping?

[image: Before resizing the browser window: a nicely spaced grid of images]

[image: During resizing: overlapping!]

[image: After resizing: back to the nice grid.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Isotope version 3 use:

```
$(window).resize(function(){ $('.grid').isotope('layout'); });
```

to avoid overlapping grid items.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [Osvaldas Valutis](http://osvaldas.info) for answering this question over on his blog post (http://osvaldas.info/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout).

--

For Masonry:

```
$(window).resize(function(){ $('#list').masonry('reload'); });
```

And the following works for me, using Isotope:

```
$(window).resize(function(){ $('#list').isotope('reLayout'); });
```

--

Thanks again, Osvaldas.

Comment: Thanks! This helped solve an issue I was having with Isotope.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you above comments...i got the answer for my problem from here but how i just want to explain to u->
i am using ajax page load using isotope so my code is-

```
var $container = $('your main container in which your all item will get listed');
 $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
     $container.isotope({
         itemSelector: 'figure',
         filter: '*',
         resizable: false,
         animationEngine: 'jquery'
     });
 });
```

after that when i call my ajax use to call this function

```
$("#filter-container").isotope('reLayout');
```

On first page load there will be some data on page so isotope will adjust all that and after appending ajax loaded data isotope will re arrange all of them.