# Have smaller divs completely fill up container div's blank space (vertically and horizontally)

Tags: html, css, layout, multiple-columns

How to build dynamic divs that fill the whole container via CSS ONLY, and not using any javascript nor any jquery! I am currently able to create the divs but the smaller ones don't fill in the vertical space.

[image]

Comment: 1. Your image link is broken, 2. your question is very broad and implementations will vary... explain in detail how you expect to achieve this in order to get help

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554798/jquery-masonry-isotope-and-fluid-images-momentary-overlap-on-window-resize)

Comment: my question is broad because I don't know formatting that well/at all. I was hoping it would work with some sort of editing of "display" and not having it be inline. I think they "How to create grid/Tile view with css?" is my best option because apparently there is some jquery to take care of this.